# Which one of juniper routers image gives me this option (GNS3)?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, gns3

I need to create the same network with cisco and juniper routers. I find tutorial to cisco. When i clicked on configuration in cisco router i have a lot of options for example WICs, its emulated by Dynamips. How i can add WIC in juniper router? I'm using Juniper Olive emulated by virtual box. Someone knows different image of juniper with this option, or knows how to switch it on? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olives aren't emulated hardware - they are actual Junos routing-engines (supervisors in Cisco terminology), so it isn't possible to add "WICs" as you would to a Cisco (which is being emulated along with the WICs) in GNS3.

You could possibly add extra Ethernet ports using the `NM-1FE-TX` option in the other Slot drop-downs but from memory when I built some physical Olives many moons ago I think this was limited to a max of 4 interfaces on top of the first `fxp0` port.